# Where is $(x-1)(x+1/2)\geq0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The solution is $x\geq 1$ or $x\leq-(1/2)$

However, I do not understand why you flip the sign of $-1/2$ but not $1$.

Comment: It is not just a question of "flipping" signs... For the product of two numbers to be positive you require both to have the same sign. Can you carry on?

Comment: ...You flip the sign of both... -1 turns into 1 and 1/2 turns into -1/2

Comment: That have to do with the fact that the roots of $(x-m)(x-n)$ are $m$ and $n$. Here you can write $(x-1)(x+1/2)$ as $(x-1)\big(x-(-1/2)\big)$, so the roots are $1$ and $-1/2.$

Answer (score 2):

The solutions to $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ are $x=a$ and $x=b$. So in this case, the solutions to $(x-1)(x+1/2)=0$ are $x=1$ and $x=-1/2$. All fine, but we want to solve the inequality, which means we're looking for a region (or set of regions).

What does $(x-1)(x+1/2) \ge 0$ mean? It means, when you multiply two numbers ($x-1$ and $x-1/2$) together, you get something positive. What multiplies to give a positive number? Either two positive numbers, or two negative numbers. So we're looking for the regions where either $x-1$ and $x+1/2$ are both positive, or they're both negative.

If $x$ is really large and positive, then adding or subtracting something as small as $1$ or $1/2$ isn't going to change much, so both the quantities will be positive. So our inequality is true over on the right-hand side of the number line. Then where does it change? Presumably where one of the two quantities flips sign - so it'll be at either $x=1$ or $x=-1/2$, and coming in from the right the first one we'll hit is $x=1$. So for $x \ge 1$, our inequality is true.

Then between $x=-1/2$ and $x=1$, we know that $x-1 < 0$ but $x + 1/2 > 0$, so we're multiplying a positive and a negative to get a negative, so our inequality isn't true any more. But then, going further, once we pass $x = -1/2$, we hit another change of sign, as $x + 1/2$ becomes negative as well. Now we're multiplying two negatives together, giving a positive, so our inequality is once again true for $x \le -1/2$.

In general, to solve these kinds of inequalities, you can find the boundaries where the sign is likely to flip - generally where the function is either zero or has an asymptote - and test values on either side of those boundaries to see if the inequality holds. For example, in this case, the boundary points are $x=1$ and $x=-1/2$, so we could test $x=-1$, $x=0$ and $x=2$ to prove that only the middle one (and hence the region between the two points) fails the test.

Answer (score 2):

You have that the original equation is $(x-1)(x+\frac{1}{2})\geq 0$. Since it is already factored we  can easily see where the zeroes of this function which are at $x=1$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. So now just plot these points on a number line.

[image]

Now you pick a point in each interval to test whether the inequality remains positive or negative. Test $x=-1,x=0,x=1.5$ where your intervals are $[-\infty,\frac{-1}{2}]$, $[\frac{-1}{2},1]$,$[1,\infty]$. I'm sure you see how I got these intervals. And from here you can see the inequality remains true on $[-\infty,\frac{-1}{2}]\cup [1,\infty]$. This can be written as $x\leq \frac{-1}{2}$ or $x\geq 1$.(We include x=1 and x=1/2 since the inequality remains true at the zeroes).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $x = 1$ or $x=-1/2$, then 
$$(x-1)(x+1/2)=0.$$

This is a degree two polynomial so it can have at most two roots. Thus, if a single point in each of $(\infty, -1/2)$, $(-1/2,1)$, and $(1,\infty)$ is positive, then then $(x-1)(x+1/2)$ is positive on that whole interval. Similarly, if a point is negative in one of those three intervals, then $(x-1)(x+1/2)$ is negative on that entire interval.

So we must check a point in each interval:

$x < -1/2$: Let's check -1 because that easy. We have $(-1-1)(-1+1/2) = 1 > 0$.

$-1/2<x<1$: Let's check 0 because that easy. We have $(0-1)(0+1/2) = -1/2 < 0$.

$1<x$: Let's check 2 because that easy. We have $(2-1)(2+1/2) = 5/2 > 0$.

Thus whenever $x\geq -1/2$ or $x\geq 1$, we have that $(x-1)(x+1/2)$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

Given: $(x-1)(x+\frac 12)\geq 0$, find the domain of $x$.

For the product to be non-negative, we require both factors to the same sign, or at least one to be zero

So we need either: $[(x-1) \geq 0 \bigwedge (x+\frac 12) > 0]$, or: $[(x-1)< 0 \bigwedge (x+\frac 12) \leq 0]$.

Which is to say: $[(x \geq 1) \bigwedge (x \geq -\frac 12)]$, or: $[(x\leq 1) \bigwedge (x \leq -\frac 12)]$.

Now: $(x \geq 1) \bigwedge (x \geq -\frac 12) \implies (x\geq 1)$

Likewise: $(x\leq 1) \bigwedge (x \leq -\frac 12) \implies (x\leq -\frac 12)$

So the solution is: $(x\geq 1)$ OR $(x\leq -\frac 12)$

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually $x \geq 1$ OR $x \leq -\frac{1}{2}$. Simple logic would dictate that both can't be true simultaneously so you shouldn't put "and" there.

There are a few ways to look at this.

One is graphically. Consider the function $y = (x-1)(x+\frac{1}{2})$. Sketch the curve like this: http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoeC0xKSh4KzAuNSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ--

Note that when the function is non-negative (i.e. on or above the y-axis), the x-values have to lie either to the left of the left-most x-intercept or to the right of the right-most x-intercept. This explanation is a little unwieldy but looking at the graph should make it clear.

The other way is simply to consider the properties of real numbers when you multiply them. To get a positive product, either both numbers have to be positive, or both numbers have to be negative. That gives:

Case 1:

$(x \geq 1) \wedge (x\geq -\frac{1}{2})$

(the symbol $\wedge$ is equivalent to "AND" in logic).

Those two conditions reduce to simply $x \geq 1$ because this satisfies both possibilities.

Case 2:

$(x \leq 1) \wedge (x\leq -\frac{1}{2})$

and again, these two conditions reduce to simply $x \leq -\frac{1}{2}$

(You can see the reason why two conditions reduce to one in these cases by drawing a simple number line).

Since either of the two possibilities can be true for the inequality to hold, there is an OR in the answer. So the solution is $(x \geq 1) \vee (x \leq -\frac{1}{2})$.

(The $\vee$ symbol refers to the logical OR).